# Can too many Events in Google Tag Manager slow down your site?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to track everything as best and as detailed as possible, so for that I am creating different events to see if form fills come from social media, ppc, etc... can too many G4 Events in GTM slow down the site?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Definitely. But unless you do completely incompetent things in GTM, it will not be very taxing, so the slowing down due to tracking is not the main concern.

There are best practices of how people track things. There are things that should never be tracked by front-end analytics, there are things that don't need to be tracked and so on.

Tracking everything is definitely the wrong idea. For so many reasons. Here are some of them:

1. All tracking requires careful maintenance. More tracking = more maintenance cost. If you don't maintain the tracking, your data quickly becomes garbage.
2. Good tracking relies on front-end support. More tracking = more front-end time wasted. You don't waste valuable resources without a good reason.
3. GTM container is not limitless. Google limits the physical size of the container. You won't be able to keep adding things to it. Moreover, you want to keep your tracking concise: less tags, less triggers, more information in payloads.
4. Too much data in GA makes it difficult to get what you need, plus Google Analytics has its own limits for the data dimensions. Plus, if your analytics ever gets good enough to be ETLed to better places, ETL will become more expensive due to your extra data.
5. The more things you have in GTM, the harder it is to scale or migrate the logic to other TMSes, or even to pure JS. Occam's razor is a good thing to keep in mind when working with GTM. And with GA. And with anything else, probably.

When GTM affects the page speed, it's important to understand what happens. First, it's not Network since the container never becomes too large to load and all the subsequent network interactions are typically small and not very frequent (third party pixels) or batched (GA4), so the Network remains unaffected, unless you do things there unrelated to analytics.

There only two things left that can typically affect the performance: memory leaks and CPU usage. Memory consumption/leaks due to poorly written JS only relates to poorly written CHTML tags and CJS variables. CPU issues are more complex. Many ways to affect CPU: poorly written CSS selectors, DOM manipulations, JS/CJS code or the heavy use of inherently heavy triggers like the timing triggers and the element visibility triggers.

In short, try to keep your core tracking brief and efficient. Arbitrarily, down to about ten triggers and five tags. I usually keep all my GA4 tracking to two or three tags: one for page_views, one for EEC events and one for all other events. Although it could be just one for all. This should typically cover 80% of my overall tracking. The rest 20% would typically require much more tags and triggers, and be generally unrelated to GA4. But that's normal.

When a stakeholder comes to an analyst and asks them to track something new, a good analyst will refuse unless there's a clear business value to be gained from that tracking. Overzealous tracking is a trait of a junior analyst and should be worked on.

Answer (score 0):

GTM is the slowest loading nd largest sized JS on my site and the single cause of google page speed and core web vitals failing. It makes a huge impact on 'slow 4g' loading time. While on fast networks it is not a big deal.